# c++ issue reading file into struct

Tags: c++, ifstream, cin

When running in terminal I get  segmentation fault when the following code is executed. In Xcode it didn't work either, but it let the program continue anyway and I just assumed it was a file path issue. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? The issue comes when `createPuzzleList` is called.

```
enum attribute_t {MONEY, TIME, INTEL};
enum action_t {PENALTY, REWARD};
const ushort MAX_NUM_ACTIONS = 3;

struct action {
    action_t actType;
    attribute_t attType;
    ushort points;
};
struct puzzle {
    string question;
    string key;
    ushort numActions;
    action actionArray[MAX_NUM_ACTIONS];
    puzzle* nextPuzzle;
};

typedef puzzle* puzzlePtr;

struct puzzleDB {
    ushort numberOfPuzzles;
    puzzlePtr puzz;
};

int createPuzzleList(puzzleDB& puzzles, string filename) {
    ifstream inStream;
    inStream.open((char*)filename.c_str());
    if (inStream.fail()) {
        cout << "Input file opening failed." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    string actType;
    string attType;
    ushort points;
    puzzlePtr cur;
    while (!inStream.eof()) {
        inStream >> puzzles.puzz->question;
        inStream >> puzzles.puzz->key;
        inStream >> puzzles.puzz->numActions;
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzles.puzz->numActions; i++) {
            action act;
            inStream >> actType;
            if (actType == "PENALTY") { act.actType = PENALTY;}
            else {act.actType = REWARD;}
            inStream >> attType;
            if (attType == "MONEY") {act.attType = MONEY;}
            else if (attType == "TIME") {act.attType = TIME;}
            else {act.attType = INTEL;}
            inStream >> points;
            act.points = points;
            puzzles.puzz->actionArray[i] = act;
        }
        puzzles.puzz = puzzles.puzz->nextPuzzle;
        puzzles.numberOfPuzzles++;
    }
    inStream.close( );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you initialise `puzzles.puzz` before calling `createPuzzleList`?

Comment: Can you provide the type-definition for "action"?

Comment: @paddy I have "puzzleDB puzzles = {0, NULL};" Which I think should initialize it to NULL?

Comment: @KodeCharlie edited to show action.

Comment: 1. You are using a linked list. 2. You are using a linked list other than `std::list`. 3. You are never allocating anything. 4. You are modifying the start pointer of your db, losing forever any data that was pointed to before. Those are just things that are visible after a cursory inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Q. Where does `puzzles.puzz` get initialized? A. Nowhere. So it points nowhere, so deferencing it via `puzzles.puzz->question` and friends gives you a SIGSEGV.